# Can't call functions in ipywidgets.HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

so I have been working with jupyter notebook using python3, and I ran into a problem that I have seaching the internet for so many hours trying to figure out.
The problem is why does this

```
from ipywidgets import HTML

HTML('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>''')
```

produce an error in the console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (testing.ipynb:1)

however it works fine whenever I inline the functions, as such

```
from ipywidgets import HTML

HTML('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";'>Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>''')
```

Is it just not work on my machine? Or does this somehow not work due to the wrapping that python does?
Does anyone have any idea why this does not work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use jupyter lab or plain jupyter notebook?

Comment: @krassowski Just jupyter notebook